# Sonarqube 6.7.1 failing to start on linux while tryint to find temp/sq-process7192036004631233695properties

Tags: linux, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I am trying to start new sonarqube LTS 6.7.1 on Red Hat Enterprise 7 with x64 architechture and failing.

Logs show ->

```
2017.12.22 07:52:27 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2017.12.22 07:52:27 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2017.12.22 07:52:35 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2017.12.22 07:52:35 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [/opt/sonarqube]: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java_1.8_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp -Xms512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -server -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonarqube/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-42.1.4.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process7192036004631233695properties
2017.12.22 07:52:42 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2017.12.22 07:52:42 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 143
2017.12.22 07:52:42 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2017.12.22 07:52:42 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

I believe the problem is that server is trying to find file /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process7192036004631233695properties. This path looks incorrect.

Please help share if there is any workaround to solve this problem.

Comment: That's only _sonar.log_ content, which shows minimal information. Review [Troubleshooting documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Troubleshooting) to understand  latest log structure, check contents of _web.log_ (as _web_ is failing to start here), and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Found issue in web.log. Issue was with database setup. Thanks for pointing.